# NFA: each block of five consecutive characters contains at least two 0's

Tags: finite-automata

How can I find an NFA for such a language, considering the alphabet to be {0, 1}. I've tried deriving it from the DFA (@Steven) and the regular expression (@Yuval Filmus), but no luck.

Comment: Any DFA is also a NFA.

Answer (score 2):

Your DFA *is* already a NFA, so you're done.